# Enrich CSV with metadata from database

Tags: sql, node.js, etl, data-integration

I've been looking around for a lightweight, scaleable solution to enrich a CSV file with additional metadata from a database. Each line in the CSV represents a data item and the columns the metadata belonging to that item.

Basically I have a CSV extract and I need to add additional metadata from a database. The metadata can be accessed via ODBC or REST API call.

I have a number of options in my head but I'm looking for other ideas. My options are as follows:

Import the CSV into a database table, apply the additional metadata with sql UPDATE statements by finding the necessary metadata with SELECT statements, and then export the data back into CSV format. For this solution I was thinking to use an ETL tool which may be a bit heavyweight to tackle this problem.

I also thought about a NodeJS based solution where I read the CSV in, call web service to get the metadata and write back the data into the CSV file. The CSV can be however quite large with potentially tens of thousands of rows so this could be heavy on memory or in case of line-by-line processing not very performant.

If you have a better solution in mind, please post. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've come up with a couple of pretty good ideas here already.

Running with your first suggestion using an ETL tool to enrich your CSV files, you should check out https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector

It's a continuous ingestion approach, so you could even monitor a directory of CSV files to load as you get them. While there's no specific functionality yet for doing lookups in a database, its certainly possible in a number of ways (including writing your own custom logic in Java, or a script in python or JavaScript).

*Full disclosure I work on this project.